# how to convert python object type mm/dd/yyyy to y-m-d date type in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

Yesss...I know there are a million answers but any answer worked for me. I have a column with type object mm/dd/yyyy like this (01/01/1948) and I am trying to convert it to 1948-01-01 00:00 (date type).

I tried the following answers:

```
def conv_dates_series(df, col, old_date_format, new_date_format):

df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format=old_date_format).dt.strftime(new_date_format)

return(df)
```

and then:

```
old_date_format='%mm/%dd/%Y'
new_date_format='%Y-%m-%d'

conv_dates_series(nypd_complaint, nypd_complaint['CMPLNT_FR_DT'], old_date_format, 
new_date_format)
```

the error i got for this one is:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['02/11/2015', '03/17/2012', '10/27/2016', '11/27/2014', '12/11/2013',\n       '08/28/2013', '12/04/2013', '09/14/2013', '01/31/2013', '09/17/2016',\n       ...\n       '07/21/2018', '01/03/2018', '09/11/2018', '01/15/2018', '08/07/2018',\n       '12/02/2018', '01/20/2018', '08/03/2018', '12/10/2018', '11/15/2018'],\n      dtype='object', length=6982552)] are in the [columns]"

I also tried:

```
nypd_complaint['CMPLNT_FR_DT'].strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
```

And:

```
nypd_complaint['CMPLNT_FR_DT'] = nypd_complaint['CMPLNT_FR_DT'].astype(np.datetime64)
```

And:

```
nypd_complaint['CMPLNT_FR_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(nypd_complaint['CMPLNT_FR_DT'] 
).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

And:

I tried to use `parse`

I got a few errors but all of them were almost the same, like: "out of range..." etc...

thank you

**PS: The goal is to drop every value from 2015 or less**

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('01/11/1948',format='%m/%d/%Y')` works for me, note that a `strftime` object is _not_ a `date` or `datetime` object. What's the end goal here?

Comment: @Manakin hi, The goal is to drop every value from the year 2015 or less

Comment: you just need to cast the object to datetime then filter it: `df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'],format='%m/%d/%Y')` `df[df['date_col'].dt.year > 2015]`

Comment: I still getting: `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1018-12-10 00:00:00`

Comment: assuming that's not a a valid datetime use the `errors` argument `df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'],format='%m/%d/%Y',errors='coerce')`

Comment: yeap it workssssss...thanks,!